# Continuous Integration Tooling running on AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, continuous-integration

Are there any Continuous Integration tools that will run on Google App Engine?

Comment: What platform, java or python?  Are you looking for a tool that you can use to continually test your app engine project, or are you looking for a CI tool that will run on app engine, which you can use to test something else?

Comment: I understand the question as "a CI tool that will run on app engine"? If this is what you are looking for, in my experience EC2 will be better suited for that.

Comment: @Pascal Thanks for your advice. I was hoping to stay free, I will look into the costs of EC2 for small projects.

Comment: The per-request limitations of GAE seem fundamentally incompatible with the needs of a continuous integration tool. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Nicholas Your right, the limitations of app engine do seem totally incompatible with the needs of a CI tool. But why I am asking = Free CI Server hosting, why not ask. I'm a developer and I am pretty retarded when it comes to administration. I can muck my way though, but it would be nice if I could just pop up a CI server for free. I am most likely going to go to EC2 tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so. The Google App Engine secure sandbox environment doesn't seem compatible with the requirements of all CI engine I know (writing to the file system is a basic need of any engine to checkout sources, to compile them, to log during tests, to  build reports, etc).

As I said in a comment, Amazon EC2 **is** appropriate for running a CI engine and I know many enterprise using it for this purpose. You should really look into this direction.

Answer (score 3):

Recently, [Cloudbees](http://www.cloudbees.com/dev.cb) bring this fonctionnality :

> Google App Engine users can now run Jenkins continuous integration in the cloud by signing up at appengine.cloudbees.com. Jenkins will monitor your projects’ source code for any changes, run the necessary builds and tests, and notify your team of any problems - or automatically deploy the application to Google App Engine if everything looks good.

Answer (score 2):

At the end of the day, an app engine app is just python code or java code.  You can use your favorite CI tool to build your app, run unit tests, and deploy to whatever test server you want, either local using the dev server, or to the cloud if you really wanted to...  What extra features are you looking for?

**EDIT:  Now that I understand the question is about CI that runs on app engine, not CI *for* app engine, my answer above is pretty much useless.**

Comment: I'm not sure how I could make the question more specific. A CI that runs on Google App Engine. IE something-ci.appspot.com give me my Hudson or something. 

Google App Engine has very specific constants, such as it can't write to the file system and such so Hudson obviously can't be run on app engine even tho it is java code.

Comment: gotcha.  my answer is useless then.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the [currently experimental] traffic splitting feature,
with the cookie option, for sending new clients to a new version.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/trafficsplitting

Leave your current version in place, deploy your new version to staging, test it,
and when you want all new clients to access the version,
just have a request filter which sets a short-lived redirect-cookie for all new clients.

So long as you check for this cookie before you set it,
all existing clients will see the old version, and all new clients get the new version.

If you keep the most recent cookie value in memcached-backed-by-ds {use expiry dates!}, you can implement continuous integration with a single request filter; just set the datastore singleton to your new traffic splitting cookie, and you're good to go.

Comment: Also, now that you can trigger deployments via git push, running CI in an appengine enviroment is easier than ever!! I believe that the new compute engine release will also run your maven tests automatically before deploying new versions.  /win/  https://cloud.google.com/tools/repo/push-to-deploy

Answer (score 0):

Directly with app engine I dont think this is possible. My understanding of how AppEngine works (which I admit is fairly limited) indicates that it would be possible to have a series of services that work together to accomplish this. Basically you need a service which is a proxy for your storage system, and one which is a proxy for your build service (both of these cannot be on AppEngine). AppEngine can then monitor these services performing the relevant copy and build metaphors.

If the thing being built is in itself an application you could automatically deploy it, and then use the AppEngine service to connect to it and test it.

I dont think it would be more effective than having a local CI instance, and it woul, at least in the short term be more complicated to setup and maintain.

Again, my current understanding of AppEngine is limited to only what I have used it for with Google Wave and a few other small projects.